# What variable types can / should I use as meteor.js Session variables?

Tags: meteor, session-variables

I've been doing `Session.set('currentlyActiveDocument',mydocument._id)` but this means I end up doing `MyCollection.findOne(Session.get('currentlyActiveDocument'))` very often. I wondered if it would be ok to just do `Session.set('currentlyActiveDocument',mydocument)` and save me those extra db lookups. That is, use an object itself (document, in this case) as a session variable rather than its ID. I don't care if reactively dependant functions are re-run when I change properties of `mydocument`.

I actually tried this recently and encountered the surprising problem that a method of the object (`mydocument`, except it wasn't a document in that case, just a JS object) did not show up on the other end when I did `foo`=Session.get(myobject). `foo.myMethod()` returned undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any type of object that EJSON can encode. To see more details on this see http://docs.meteor.com/#ejson.

You could also add your own EJSON extensions for custom types.

The reason your JS object doesn't (fully) store in a Session hash is that it contains a function, the functions are ignored by EJSON.